# leadbolt html ads not showing

Tags: javascript, android, html, leadbolt

I am trying to integrate leadbolt html ads into my Android application that uses WebView to show html for user interface.

I use this simple tag that my leadbolt control panel provided me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.leadbolt.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=1111111111"></script>
```

where 1111111111 is my section id

it shows simply nothing, and even the url http://ad.leadbolt.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=1111111111 returns nothing

Is it possible that some setting in android is needed to be done so that the html call can be verified with the application api key?

Answer (score 1):

```
WebView leadBoltAd = findViewById(R.id.leadBoltBanner);
String leadBoltAdHtmlString = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"src=\"http://ad.leadbolt.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=1111111111\"></script>";
leadBoltAd.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
leadBoltAd.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
leadBoltAd.loadData(leadBoltAdHtmlString,"text/html","utf-8");
```

No need of API for Webview Banner Ad implementaion.